# Organise datatable using unique values from one column as new column headers in R

Tags: r, datatable

I have a data table that includes 4 columns: "file", "date", "name", and "rt".  There are 25 different names, which apply to hundreds of observations.  I want to rearrange the data table so that the unique names are column headers, with multiple rt values corresponding to dates.  There may be more than one observation of each name on any given date.

So there should only be one row for each "file", (there are currently 25), instead of the "name" column, I want a column for each unique name.  I also want to be able to do this rearranging programmatically because there will be other scenarios where there is a different list of names.  But for this current scenario, the idea is to have one row per file, with columns labelled 'file', 'date', name 1, name 2, etc., and then have the rt data populate the table.

Input data looks like this:

[image: input data]

The output should be arranged something like this:

[image: output format]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pivot_wider` should work: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = rt)
```

Comment: Turns out this works perfectly.  I initially thought it didn't work, but it was actually my data that was faulty.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```r
colnames(file)[5:29]<- unique(file$name)
```

Comment: no, its not just about creating new column names, its about rearranging the data that corresponds to the unique names